# DriveApp.createFile( e.parameter.blob); Not executing

Tags: google-apps-script, blob

In google app scripts, the following line throws error:

```
DriveApp.createFile( e.parameter.fileupBlob);
```

Where `fileupBlob` is hidden field in the  form with a BLOB stored in it.

Error thrown when executed:

> Cannot find method createFile((class)). (line 23, file "Code", project
>   "saving")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! The javascript library was returning string dataURI and i replaced the first part of dataURI in jquery:

```
strDataURI=strDataURI.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
document.getElementById("blobobj").value = strDataURI;
```

Then i was able to create the image

```
var str=Utilities.base64Decode(e.blobobj);
var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(str).setContentType('image/png');
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument of `DriveApp.createFile` must be a blob.
The value returned by `e.parameter.varName` is a string.

Therefore the error you get.  The only case when a blob is returned from a form is when you use a file upload widget, the hidden widget behaves like a text widget.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the blob as shown below. It is assuming you passed a valid blob. EDIT: If drive is having difficulty figuring out what type of file it is from the blob you can provide that info yourself.  Another thought is that the blob may be base64 encoded. You may have to decode it before creating the new blob. You haven't posted any code so I can't tell what is going on.

```
var name = "fileName.png";
var contentType = "image/png";
var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameter.fileupBlob, contentType, name);
DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob);
```

Comment: e.parameter.fileupBlob is a base64 string and when i tried to execute it showed --
Blob object must have non-null name for this operation

Comment: I was able to create the file(image) but there is no image

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```js
let imageBlob = images[0].getBlob();
let name = 'fileName.jpeg';
let contentType = 'image/jpeg';
let fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(imageBlob.getBytes(), contentType, name);
let imageFile = folder.createFile(fileBlob).setName('ravgeet.jpeg');
```